# Prove formula of differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, normed-spaces

Prove without using any theorem or definition in your script:

$\lim \limits_{c \to 0} \frac{ \lVert f(x+c)-f(x)-\mathbf{Df}(x)\cdot
c \rVert }{ \lVert c \rVert } = 0$

This is defined as Definition in our script. Therefore it is not allowed to use anything from it. But how can i show this? I also looked in a few books and other scripts. It is defined everywhere but has not been proven.

Someone said i am allowed to use max-norm because all Norms are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is this making everything easier?

Comment: @kimchilover this was wrong :-S of course ^^

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking, nor what your hypotheses are.  Do you have some particular $f$ for which you want to prove the stated limit?  Or some class of functions?

Comment: What is $f$, what ist $Df$ if you are not allowed to use any definitions? And why is this tagged as functional analysis?

Comment: This follows from the very definition of Fréchet derivative.

Comment: Given your rules of the game your so called formula is just a pixel heap.